# Spring Cloud Contract org.junit.ComparisonFailure: expected: <[200]> but was:<[404]> while running tests

Tags: spring-cloud-contract

I've setup a sample project to use Spring Cloud Contract 2.0.0.RC1 just to get it working. When I run the tests I receive the error message:

```
Tests run: 1, Failures: 1, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 3.188 sec <<< FAILURE!
validate_shouldGetProfile(com.example.contractdemoserver.ContractdemoserverTest)  Time elapsed: 0.443 sec  <<< FAILURE!
org.junit.ComparisonFailure: expected:<[200]> but was:<[404]>
at com.example.contractdemoserver.ContractdemoserverTest.validate_shouldGetProfile(ContractdemoserverTest.java:27)
```

The project builds and runs fine otherwise. I've tried numerous things to resolve this test error including checking to see if the ContractVerifieriBase is being called by adding a System.out.println() message to Contractdemoserverbase.setup() (see below), and it is being called.

I've been trying to follow/emulate just the producer project from here (which runs and tests fine):

https://github.com/spring-cloud-samples/spring-cloud-contract-samples

What am I doing wrong?

Project Structure is laid out in idea like so:

[image]

ContractdemoserverApplication:

```
package com.example.contractdemoserver;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class ContractdemoserverApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ContractdemoserverApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

ServerDefaultController:

```
package com.example.contractdemoserver;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;

@Controller
public class ServerDefaultController {

    public static final String controllerName = "test";
    public static final String controllerPath = "/" + controllerName;

    @RequestMapping(value = controllerPath, headers={"application/json"})
    @ResponseBody
    public TestObject get(){
        return new TestObject(1001, new String[0]);
    }
}
```

TestObject:

```
package com.example.contractdemoserver;

public class TestObject {

    private int id;
    private String[] cards;

    public TestObject(){}

    public TestObject(int id, String[] cards){
        setId(id);
        setCards(cards);
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String[] getCards() {
        return cards;
    }

    public void setCards(String[] cards) {
        this.cards = cards;
    }
}
```

ContractdemoserverBase:

```
package com.example.contractdemoserver;

import io.restassured.module.mockmvc.RestAssuredMockMvc;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringRunner;

@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
public abstract class ContractdemoserverBase {

    @Before
    public void setup() {
        RestAssuredMockMvc.standaloneSetup(new ServerDefaultController());
    }

}
```

shouldGetProfile.groovy:

````
package contracts.contractdemoserver

import org.springframework.cloud.contract.spec.Contract

Contract.make {
    description("""
Represents a successful scenario of getting a response from the /test endpoint.

```
given:
    nothing
when:
    a request for a Test is made
then:
    returns a test object with id 1001 and no cards
```

""")
    request {
        method 'GET'
        url '/test'
        headers {
            contentType(applicationJson())
        }
    }
    response {
        status 200
        body("""
            {
                "id":1001,
                "cards":[]
            }
        """)
        headers {
            contentType(applicationJson())
        }
    }
}
````

pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>contractdemoserver</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>server</name>
    <description>POC Server for Service Contract Testing</description>

    <properties>
        <docker-maven-plugin-version>0.25.0</docker-maven-plugin-version>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <maven-resources-plugin.version>3.0.2</maven-resources-plugin.version>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <spring-boot-dependencies-version>2.0.1.RELEASE</spring-boot-dependencies-version>
        <spring-cloud.version>Finchley.BUILD-SNAPSHOT</spring-cloud.version>
        <spring-cloud-contract.version>2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT</spring-cloud-contract.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-contract-verifier</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-boot-dependencies-version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.0.2.RELEASE</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-contract-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-cloud-contract.version}</version>
                <extensions>true</extensions>
                <configuration>
                    <!-- <baseClassForTests>com.example.contractdemoserver.ContractVerifierBase</baseClassForTests> -->
                    <packageWithBaseClasses>com.example.contractdemoserver</packageWithBaseClasses>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>


    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-snapshots</id>
            <name>Spring Snapshots</name>
            <url>http://repo.spring.io/libs-snapshot-local</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-milestones</id>
            <name>Spring Milestones</name>
            <url>http://repo.spring.io/libs-milestone-local</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-releases</id>
            <name>Spring Releases</name>
            <url>http://repo.spring.io/release</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>spring-snapshots</id>
            <name>Spring Snapshots</name>
            <url>http://repo.spring.io/libs-snapshot-local</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </pluginRepository>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>spring-milestones</id>
            <name>Spring Milestones</name>
            <url>http://repo.spring.io/libs-milestone-local</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </pluginRepository>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>spring-plugin-snapshots</id>
            <name>Spring Snapshots</name>
            <url>http://repo.spring.io/plugins-snapshot-local</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </pluginRepository>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>spring-plugin-milestones</id>
            <name>Spring Milestones</name>
            <url>http://repo.spring.io/plugins-release-local</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>

</project>
```

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you upload this to github?

Comment: @MarcinGrzejszczak - see: https://github.com/ffs-brianh/contractdemoserver

Comment: @MarcinGrzejszczak Hey I figured it out, `@RequestMapping` did not have `produces = "application/json"`. Should it be returning a 404 error, or is this a bug with Spring Cloud Contract?

Comment: Yes it behaves correctly. You don't have a matching header for the request

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The method `@RequestMapping(value = controllerPath, headers={"application/json"})` is missing/requires the property `produces = "application/json"` in order for Contract testing to work. Classic Spring feedback.

Comment: It's not requiring those for contract testing to work. It's required to make the tests generated from your contracts pass. You got exactly what you wanted. Just remove tge header from contract response and you'll see that your tests will pass. Spring does exactly what you told it to do